# Emoji not encoding

Tags: java, json, decode, encode, emoji

I am retrieving twitter tweets and attempting to save them to a flat file. I have the following code:

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(tweets);

 byte[] utf8JsonString = jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8");

 String utf8json = new String(utf8JsonString, "UTF-8");

System.out.println( utf8json);
```

Output:

```
..."id":768260789744443392,"text":"#emojicity5 ?","source"...
```

The emoji (just after #emojicity5) are appearing as ?.  I have attempted to endode using UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, and UTF-32LE but to no avail. This system is using `jdk 1.6` and `3.0.3 of twitter4j`.  What am I missing here?

Comment: May the problem be more related to the font in your console? The value should be right but your output cannot display it.

Answer (score 0):

String already contains Unicode, no need to convert back to the same string.
When to or from `byte[]` one needs to indicate the encoding of those bytes.

However the problem is that the console probably has no Unicode encoding like UTF-8 and even might not have the emoji in the fonts. A problem of `System.out.println`. In this case System.out was in some other encoding that could not represent the emoji and instead printed a question mark.

What you can do to check whether the emoji arrived, is dump the Unicode code points.

In java 8:

```
jasonString.toCodePoints()
        .filter(cp -> cp >= 256)
        .forEach(cp -> {
            System.out.printf("U+%X = %s%n",
                cp, Character.getName(cp));
         });

boolean containsEmoji(String s) {
    return s.codePoints().anyMatch(cp ->
        UnicodeBlock.of(cp).equals(UnicodeBlock.EMOTICONS));
}
```